# Httml Button in Django app to run a Python script

Tags: html, django

I am using Geonode that is actually a django app installed inside a docker container. What I want to do is, to edit an html page of my app and add an extra button that when the user presses it a python script will run.

So far, I have added the button in the html page, a function in my views.py file and a url in the urls.py but it doesnt seem to work.

**html page**

```
<a href={{ request.get_full_path }} class="btn btn-primary btn-block" data-dismiss="modal" name="layer_approve" id="layer_approve">{% trans "Approve Layer" %}</a>
```

**views.py**

```
def layer_approval(request):
    # I keep it simple to make sure it works
    return redirect('www.google.gr')
```

**urls.py**

```
from django.urls import path
urlpatterns += [
    url(r'^layer_approval/', include('geonode.views.layer_approval'))
]
```

I am completely new to Django. Any advice?

Answer (score 0):

Your method name and URL-pattern **layer_approval** and pass button name or id **layer_approve**.

Comment: I have made the change but still doesnt work.